# Xamarin - Record Audio As RIFF WAV

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Right now, I am using `MediaRecorder` as my main recorder for Audio, but I need to convert it to `PCM` and `RIFF WAV` as my output, I have looked for certain libraries to help me e.g.`NReco` `BASS.net` (not free though) and `NAudio` (This thing only works for windows)  but there's no hope.

Would this be possible with `AudioRecord` ? And if I use `AudioRecord` should I be the one transforming it to have a `RIFF WAV` header? Or are there libraries that can do this?